# Java .properties file and C# .settings file

Tags: java, c#, settings, properties-file

I'm working on converting a Java code to C#.

The Java code writes and reads 3 key pieces of data in the application into a **.properties** file. This may even go on for several hundred lines.

`Properties prop = new Properties();`

I have looked at several C# replacements for .properties files and I've come up with 3 possibilities.

`.settings`
`.ini`
`.config`

From the non-existent experience I have with these 3 file types, I was thinking that **.settings** is what I need.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and give me some info on how to work with the best file type. (I've looked into reading and writing to .settings files and there's not much to go on)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio you would replace that with `.settings` indeed. If you right click the project and choose to `properties` then select the `Settings` tab and you have a nice link to create one if not already there. you can obviously create one using the "add new item"

It can hold standard type such as `string`, `int`, `double` and even more complex one such as `Datatable` and even custom object

Adding to this, settings also have a scope where you can define at user or application level.

Comment: Please note that access to such a setting is as easy as `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`. Also, if you need to *modify* settings from your code as well, use "User settings".

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you tell me how to access an already created file called (for eg) exec.settings. A code segment would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately i never really used that, i'm more a fan of database settings either local or through WCF service whenever i can. you should google `loading multiple setting files`

Answer (score 2):

Java `.properties` file is used to store application settings.

Equivalent for .net application is a `.config` file. You can then use the whole infrastructure for reading/editing settings.

You can have these setting also in separate file or somewhere else by creating a configuration provider.

Comment: Is there a difference from editing a text file? Any helpful links? Thanks.